# How to manually set the Id of an element and access the list elements of the having same Id's in a list <li><\li> tag?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, activeadmin

I am using a list for listing the orders in active admin and i have used  the `jQuery` to change the value of a textfield on the basis of the value in other text field. For this purpose,in Active Admin, I have a model of `Order Line Items` and `Sales Order`.

A `Sales Order` `has_many` `Order_line_items`.

On the form person has to select the customer. then add new line item and he can keep adding as much items as he want.

But when I want to change the Quantity of any item except the first one,  the `jQuery` did not work and there is no change.

Here is some code for reference.

Sales Order Model: `SalesOrder.rb`

```
class SalesOrder < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :order_line_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_line_items, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Order_Line_items Model: `order_line_items.rb`

```
class OrderLineItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :sales_order
    belongs_to :product
end
```

`jQuery` Used for changing the value:

```
$(document).on("change", "#select_product", (e) ->
  customer_id = $('#select_customer').val();
  product_id = $('#select_product').val();
  if customer_id != "" && product_id != ""
    $.ajax
      type: "GET"
      url: "/get_product_rate"
      dataType: "html"
      data: { customer_id: customer_id, product_id: product_id}
      success: (data) ->
        $("#rate").val(parseInt(data));
      error: (e) ->
        console.log e
)
$(document).on("change", "#quantity", (e) ->
  rate = $('#rate').val();
  quantity = $('#quantity').val();
  if rate != "" && quantity != ""
   $.ajax
      type: "GET"
      url: "/get_total"
      dataType: "html"
      data: { quantity: quantity, rate: rate}
      success: (data) ->
        $("#total").val(parseInt(data));
      error: (e) ->
        console.log e
)
```

Active Admin Form HTML:

```
<li class="has_many_container order_line_items" data-sortable-start="0"><fieldset class="inputs_ol inputs has_many_fields"><ol><li class="select2 input optional" id="sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_0_product_id_input"><label for="select_product" class="label">Product</label><select class="select2-input select2-hidden-accessible" id="select_product" style="width: 80% !important" placeholder="Select Product" name="sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][0][product_id]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Pet of 1.5 Litre</option>
<option value="2">test product</option>
<option value="3">hello1</option></select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 80%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-select_product-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-select_product-container" title=""><span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span></span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

</li><li class="number input optional numeric stringish" id="sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_0_rate_input"><label for="rate" class="label">Price</label><input id="rate" step="any" type="number" name="sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][0][rate]">

</li><li class="number input optional numeric stringish" id="sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_0_quantity_input"><label for="quantity" class="label">Quantity</label><input id="quantity" step="any" type="number" value="1" name="sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][0][quantity]">

</li><li class="number input optional numeric stringish" id="sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_0_total_input"><label for="total" class="label">Total</label><input id="total" step="any" type="number" name="sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][0][total]">

</li><li><a class="button has_many_remove" href="#">Remove</a></li></ol></fieldset><a class="button has_many_add" data-html="<fieldset class=&quot;inputs_ol inputs has_many_fields&quot;><ol><li class=&quot;select2 input optional&quot; id=&quot;sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD_product_id_input&quot;><label for=&quot;select_product&quot; class=&quot;label&quot;>Product</label><select class=&quot;select2-input&quot; id=&quot;select_product&quot; style=&quot;width: 80% !important&quot; placeholder=&quot;Select Product&quot; name=&quot;sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD][product_id]&quot;><option value=&quot;&quot;></option>
<option value=&quot;1&quot;>Pet of 1.5 Litre</option>
<option value=&quot;2&quot;>test product</option>
<option value=&quot;3&quot;>hello1</option></select>

</li><li class=&quot;number input optional numeric stringish&quot; id=&quot;sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD_rate_input&quot;><label for=&quot;rate&quot; class=&quot;label&quot;>Price</label><input id=&quot;rate&quot; step=&quot;any&quot; type=&quot;number&quot; name=&quot;sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD][rate]&quot; />

</li><li class=&quot;number input optional numeric stringish&quot; id=&quot;sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD_quantity_input&quot;><label for=&quot;quantity&quot; class=&quot;label&quot;>Quantity</label><input id=&quot;quantity&quot; step=&quot;any&quot; type=&quot;number&quot; value=&quot;1&quot; name=&quot;sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD][quantity]&quot; />

</li><li class=&quot;number input optional numeric stringish&quot; id=&quot;sales_order_order_line_items_attributes_NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD_total_input&quot;><label for=&quot;total&quot; class=&quot;label&quot;>Total</label><input id=&quot;total&quot; step=&quot;any&quot; type=&quot;number&quot; name=&quot;sales_order[order_line_items_attributes][NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD][total]&quot; />

</li><li><a class=&quot;button has_many_remove&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;>Remove</a></li></ol></fieldset>" data-placeholder="NEW_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_RECORD" href="#">Add New Order line item</a></li>
```

I want to track the change so that i will change the other fields accordingly. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "*having same IDs*" - well that shouldn't work as all elements must have unique IDs to be valid HTML (happens that *some* browsers are lenient on this rule)

Comment: But in Rails ActiveAdmin, we don't have option or any way to change the HTML. Actually this is the main problem. :(

Comment: If you can’t fix the duplicate IDs issue, then you will have to resort to other means of selecting the correct elements, than IDs … Classes, relationships between elements (selecting children/parents/siblings, where applicable), …

Comment: I can't, in good conscience, provide a full answer to fix duplicate IDs.  But you can work with this in jquery: inside the event handler, `var fieldset = $(this).closest("fieldset");` then `$("#rate", fieldset).val(xxx)`.   (hard to tell due to the badly laid out HTML, but I would expect, as there's a fieldset, that all related inputs would to be in that fieldset)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you very much for your time. your answer help me lot.